# what would cause [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable to fail silently?

Tags: powershell

I'm running this ps command:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable( "Path"
, $env:Path + "; D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\bin"
, System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine )
```

I've started powershell as an admin. To me, that command should add the "; D:\Program..." string to the Path variable of the current machine. Yet, it doesn't and there's no failure. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me and does not need to restart console

```
PS C:\Users> $env:Path = "$($env:Path);c:\Scripts"
PS C:\Users> $env:Path
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System
32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\Co
mmon Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;c:\Scripts
```

This works only for the current session though. If you need to persist the updated path variable, you need to use the method in your question and restart the shell.

Comment: Good tip, thanks. Wonder why one would need restart and not other?

Comment: BTW, the tip I showed works only for the current session. If you restart PowerShell, $env:Path will be back to its original value. I have edited my answer to clatify this.

Comment: Yes but you can add it to your $env:Profile, or $env:CurrentUserAllHosts profile and it will be added every time you start a session.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found the answer shortly after: you have to **restart powershell** to see any modified environment variables.

Comment: only when using the .net method... does it need to be set across the entire enviorment or is it only necessary in powershell environments?

Comment: Well for this situation I needed it for Java. So all enviros.